# Some questions about C++ from a C# developer

Tags: c++

I have some questions about C++ from a C# developer.

For a few days I have been looking at some C++ code, and I have the following questions:

1. When do use `Foo::`, `Foo.` and `Foo->` ?
2. When do I use a real constructor and when just `String a;` (sometimes I need to do something like `String a("foo");`)
3. What is the difference between these signatures: `int foo(int a)` and `int foo(int &a)`?

Comment: have you try googling this question?

Comment: I suggest you invest in a beginners book on C++, as all this (and much more) should be explained in it.

Comment: @triclosan: why does that matter? Is Google a better place to find programming answers than SO?

Comment: This wasn't mentioned, so... `int Foo::bar()` - Foo:: Is also used when writing out of line method definitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`::` is used either to explicitly specify a namespace (`std::string`, for example, for the string class in the namespace `std`), or for static members of a class.

`.` is used much as in C#, to refer to a member of a class.

`->` is used with pointers. If `p` is a pointer to an object `obj`, then `p->x` has the same meaning as `obj.x`.

> when do i use a real constructor and when just String a; (sometimes i need to do something like String a("foo");)

When you need to. `String a` is roughly equivalent to C#'s `a = new String()` (with the caveat that if `String` is a non-POD type, it may contain uninitialized members.)

If you need `a` initialized to a specific value, you do that. (either with `String a("foo")`, or with `String a = "foo"`)

> where is the difference between these signatures: int foo(int a) and int foo(int &a)?

The `&` denotes a reference. It's not *quite* a C# reference, but there are similarities. In C#, you have value types and reference types, and reference types are always passed by reference.

In C++, there's no such distinction. Every type can be passed by value or by reference. The type `T&` is a *reference to T*. In other words, given the following code:

```
void foo(int& j);
void bar(int j);

int i = 42;

foo(i);
bar(i);
```

`foo` will get a *reference* to `i`, which means it it can modify the value of `i`.
`bar` will get *a copy* of `i`, which means that any modifications it makes will not be reflected in `i`.

You often use `const T&` (a reference to `const T`) as a way to avoid the copy, while still preventing the callee from modifying the object.

Answer (score 2):

1: Assuming you which to call a method

> Foo::theMethod(...)

is for example used when calling a static method of a class Foo

> Foo.theMethod(...)

is when you have an object named Foo

> Foo->theMethod(...)

is when you have a pointer to a object of named Foo

2:

> String a;

calls the default constructor that takes no arguments

> String a("foo")

calls a overloaded constructor

3:

> int foo(int &a)

takes a reference to an integer, so within the method you are able to manipulate a.

> int foo(int a)

makes a copy, manipulating it wont have any effect of the actual parameter passed in after leaving the method.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1:

It depends on what `Foo` is.  The `::` operator is called the scope
resolution operator; the operand on the right must be a namespace or a
class, and the operand to the left a member of the namespace or class.
If `Foo` is a class, `Foo::` can be used to access a static member, or
from within a member of a derived class, to access the member of the
base class: e.g.:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void f();
    static void g();
};

int h()
{
    Foo::g();
}

class Derived : public Foo
{
public:
    virtual void f()
    {
        Foo::f();  // Call function in base class...
    }
}
```

It's often used to access namespace members as well, e.g. `std::cout`
(the `cout` object in namespace `std`).

The `.` operator is a member access operator, and requires an object (or
a reference to an object) as the left hand operand.  Thus (using the
above definitions):

```
Foo obj;
obj.f();

void i( Foo& rFoo )
{
    rFoo.f();
}
```

It can also be used to access static members, if you have an instance:

```
Foo obj;
obj.g();
```

The `->` is very much like the `.` operator, except that it takes a
pointer to an instance, rather than an instance, and (very importantly)
it can be overloaded.  Thus:

```
Foo* obj;
obj->g();
//  And if Ptr is a user defined type with an overloaded
//  `operator->` which returns a Foo*
Ptr obj;
obj->g();
```

Again, you can also use this syntax to access a static member, if you
have a pointer to an object.

Question 2:

The definition `String a;` calls a real constructor.  You use `String
a;` when you want the default constructor; the one with no parameters.
You use `String a( "foo" );` when you want the constructor which takes a
`char const*` (or a `char const (&)[4]`, but that's highly unlikely, since it
will only work for a string literal with exactly three characters).

In general, when defining variables:

```
String a;               //  default constructor...
String a1();            //  NOT what it looks like: this is a
                        //  function declaration, and not the
                        //  definition of a variable!!!
String b( x, y, z );    //  constructor taking x, y and z as arguments...
String c = x;           //  implicitly convert `x` to String, then
                        //  copy constructor.
```

The last form is a bit tricky, since the copy constructor may be (and
almost always is) elided, but the legality of the program is defined by
the rule above: there must be a way of implicitly converting `x` into a
`String`, and `String` must have an accessible copy constructor.

In other contexts, e.g. `new String()`, the form with empty parameters
can be used for "value construction", which is the default constructor
if there is a user defined one, otherwise zero initialization.

Question 3:

The first is pass by value, and passes a copy of the argument to the
function.  The second is pass by reference, and passes a reference
(which behaves sort of like a hidden, automatically dereferenced
pointer) to the function.  Thus:

```
void f( int a )
{
    ++ a;       //  Modifies local copy, has no effect on the argument.
}

void g( int& a )
{
    ++ a;       //  Modifies the variable passed as an argument.
}
```

Note that in the first case, you can pass an arbitrary expression; in
the second, you must pass something called an lvalue—that is,
something you can access afterwards using a similar expression (a named
variable, or a dererenced pointer, or an element in a named array,
etc.).

Answer (score 1):

1. `String a` : construct an empty `String` object

   `String a("foo")` : construct a `String` object initalized to `"foo"`
2. `int foo(int a)` : pass `a` by value/copy to foo. Inside foo if you modify `a` , `a` will not be impacted outside foo

   `int foo(int& a)` : pass `a` by reference inside foo. If you modify `a` , `a` will also be modify once foo ended

Answer (score 0):

1. `Foo::` - Static methods

   `Foo.`  - Instance Methods when you have a stack object instance.   (`MyObject obj`)

   `Foo->` - Instance methods when you have a object pointer. (`MyObject* pObj = new MyObject()`)
2. Whenever you need to pass some value to the constructor.
3. `int&` is a reference to an `int`. Any changes to **`a`** within the method will affect **`a`** outside the method. (Equivalent to `ref` in C#)

Comment: Also remember that the operators may be overloaded.